# How to perform SQL group by operations to ignore some particular data?

Tags: sql

I have tables:

```
movies
-id
-name
genres
-id
-name
moviesgenres
-id
-name
-genreid
-movieid
```

After doing some queries

```
select mov.name, count(mgen.genreId)
from movies mov
inner join moviesGenres mgen
  on mov.id = mgen.movieId
inner join genres gen 
  on mgen.genreid = gen.id 
group by mov.name
having count(mgen.genreId) > 2
```

This produced the result as

```
 Bad Boys 3
   Novelty 3
```

The actual data from the above query seems

```
 id movie_id movie name movie genre
    1  1    Bad Boys    Comedy
    2  1    Bad Boys     Horror
    3  1    Bad Boys     Black
    4  2     Novelty     Horror
    5  2     Novelty      Black
    6  2     Novelty      Romantic
```

The case here is I just want the answer as
`Novelty 3`  
Because I do not want the movie name if it has the genre `'Comedy'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a subselect to filter movies

```
select mov.name, count(mgen.genreId)
from movies mov
inner join moviesGenres mgen
  on mov.id = mgen.movieId
inner join genres gen 
  on mgen.genreid = gen.id
where mov.id not in (select mov.id from movies mov inner join moviesGenres mgen
  on mov.id = mgen.movieId
inner join genres gen 
  on mgen.genreid = gen.id
where gen.name = 'Comedy')
group by mov.name
having count(mgen.genreId) > 2
```

Comment: I don't think that you need the subquery as there is already an inner join to genres  - enough to write 'inner join genres gen on mgen.genreid = gen.id where gen.name <> 'Comedy'

Comment: @No'amNewman this will not return the same result ie the result will be bad Boys 2 instead of exclude totally Bad Boys

Comment: I missed that requirement.